# IQueryable create query fails with error Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter after upgrading to .net 6 and ef 6

Tags: asp.net, linq, .net-6.0

I am calling a chunk of code
`

```
var m = typeof(IQueryProvider).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "CreateQuery" && x.IsGenericMethod); 
var gm = m.MakeGenericMethod(queryType);
var a = (IQueryable)gm.Invoke(provider, new object[] { expression });
```

where the provider comes from

```
    (from p in Context.Set<PointOfInterest>() select p).Provider
```

the query type is PointOfInterestDto

the expression is

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
        .Extension<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression>,
        '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.Domain.PointOfInterestAggregate.PointOfInterest,BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.DtoModels.PointOfInterestDto]>))
    ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.DtoModels.PointOfInterestDto,System.Boolean]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.Domain.PointOfInterestAggregate.PointOfInterest,BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.DtoModels.PointOfInterestDto]>(BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.Domain.PointOfInterestAggregate.PointOfInterest $pointOfInterest)
{
    .New BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.DtoModels.PointOfInterestDto(){
        Name = $pointOfInterest.Name,
        Id = $pointOfInterest.Id,
        ExtraFields = (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object])$pointOfInterest.ExtraFields
    }
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.DtoModels.PointOfInterestDto,System.Boolean]>(BibeCoffee.Logic.PointsOfInterest.DtoModels.PointOfInterestDto $o)
{
    .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(
        (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]).Call ($o.ExtraFields).get_Item("coffeeChannels"),
        .Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Boolean]>)
}

.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Boolean]>(System.Object $o) {
    .Call ((System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object])$o).ContainsKey("id") && (System.Guid).Call ((System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object])$o).get_Item("id")
    == .Constant<System.Guid>(d5471682-df51-480b-a367-35b7a918f172)
}
```

after the invoke the queryable gives this kind of error

```
Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object] AsQueryable[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])' (Parameter 'arg0')
```

Keep in mind that the extrafields property is an IDictionary<string, object> , where in this scenario is an the coffeeChannel property has an array of elemets where I want to search in it.
Also this used to work fine on previous version (ef5 , .net5)

I put a debugger on with all libraries in the sym table to chgeckt step by step what is happening internally on CreateQuery, but VS cannot step in.

I double checked the expression and looks fine to me.

I cross checked the breaking changes several, but no luck ( maybe I missed something).

Comment: Where is other code? Never tried to call `CreateQuery` dynamically. Also install [ReadableExpressions.Visualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) to simplify life with expressions.

Comment: What do you mean by other code? this is the bit that having issue.

Comment: There are a lot of variables, which initialization is unknown: `provider`, `queryType`, `expression`. I cannot read Debug expression output, but can find error in expression building code. Also what you are trying to build?

Comment: Expression is given, I will update the post with the rest.  
I am using a custom library ( that used to work on previous version) which filters on db by using OData standard.

Comment: What is this code trying to do? OData doesn't require such code. No matter how quirky it is (I had the unfortunate idea to use OData with EF Core too), it *doesn't* need reflection to generate a model or queries. Generating the Edm model can be quirky but OData *already* uses reflection to find the types and relations configured in a DbContext

Comment: Install extension which i mentioned in first comment and analyze methods and built expression accurately. It is difficult to understand what is wrong.

Comment: If you want to apply an incoming OData request to a DbSet, the easiest option is to use an action that accepts `ODataQueryOptions<Customer> options` and apply it to the DbSet, eg `var query = (IQueryable<Customer>)options.ApplyTo(_context.Customers,
AllowedQueryOptions.Skip | AllowedQueryOptions.Top);`. After that you can add any other LINQ operators you want

Comment: Unfortunately it is a legacy - custom code so I need to fix the current approach. It does not use any OData libs. I know this is not the best approach but I do not have the option of huge refactoring at the moment.  I am just trying to figure out why this expression works fine with .net 5 but not with .net 6